# More efficient way to substr to first white space in this for() loop

Tags: javascript

I'm learning js and I wanted to try and put some of the basics I've learnt so far together.

Below is what I have, I just wondered is there a more efficient way for me to get the **name** up until the first white space, instead of doing it with every loop?

For example my code would log (first loop only)

> Lewis Hamilton has an even driver number, it's 44. **Lewis** drives for
>   Mercedes.

I get the **first name** only in the for() loop **Lewis** from **name** which in full is actually **Lewis Hamilton**, by adding this to my loop `team[i].name.substr(0,team[i].name.indexOf(' '))` which is getting everything up to the first white space.

Could/Should I do this outside of my loop, is there any point and if so would it more more efficient? It's just a thought I had, I didn't know if doing it for every loop was adding extra work for every loop, when I could "predefine" it. But I don't want to predefine it by creating an array simply listing first names, I could but that doesn't answer the query I have.

Could I somehow do it outside the loop for all the full names and make them something like `team[i].firstname`, so it is just adding them in, not substr to first white space each time.

I hope that made sense :)

```js
function Driver (name, car, number) {
  this.name = name;
  this.car = car;
  this.number = number;
}

var team = [];

team[0] = new Driver ("Lewis Hamilton", "Mercedes", 44);
team[1] = new Driver ("Nico Rosberg", "Mercedes", 6);
team[2] = new Driver ("Sebastian Vettel", "Ferrari", 5);
team[3] = new Driver ("Kimi Raikkonen", "Ferrari", 7);
team[4] = new Driver ("Fernando Alonso", "McLaren", 14);
team[5] = new Driver ("Jenson Button", "McLaren", 22);
team[6] = new Driver ("Daniel Ricciardo", "Red Bull", 3);
team[7] = new Driver ("Daniil Kyvat", "Red Bull", 26);
team[8] = new Driver ("Felipe Massa", "Williams", 19);
team[9] = new Driver ("Valtteri Bottas", "Williams", 77);

for (var i = 0; i < team.length; i++) {
  if (team[i].number % 2 === 0) {
    console.log(team[i].name + " has an even driver number, it's " + team[i].number + ". " + team[i].name.substr(0,team[i].name.indexOf(' ')) + " drives for " + team[i].car + ".");
  } else {
    console.log(team[i].name + " has an odd driver number, it's " + team[i].number + ". " + team[i].name.substr(0,team[i].name.indexOf(' ')) + " drives for " + team[i].car + ".");
  }
};
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can suggest that you can make it in the constructor with a new property called `firstName`for example:

```
function Driver (name, car, number) {
    this.name = name;
    this.firstName = name.split(" ")[0]; // this is the new line;
    this.car = car;
    this.number = number;
}
```

Then you can access that like this:

```
team[i].name + " has an even driver number, it's " + team[i].number + ". " + team[i].firstName + " drives for " + team[i].car + ".";
```

Here you are the full working snippet:

```js
function Driver (name, car, number) {
  this.name = name;
  this.firstName = name.split(" ")[0];
  this.car = car;
  this.number = number;
}

var team = [];

team[0] = new Driver ("Lewis Hamilton", "Mercedes", 44);
team[1] = new Driver ("Nico Rosberg", "Mercedes", 6);
team[2] = new Driver ("Sebastian Vettel", "Ferrari", 5);
team[3] = new Driver ("Kimi Raikkonen", "Ferrari", 7);
team[4] = new Driver ("Fernando Alonso", "McLaren", 14);
team[5] = new Driver ("Jenson Button", "McLaren", 22);
team[6] = new Driver ("Daniel Ricciardo", "Red Bull", 3);
team[7] = new Driver ("Daniil Kyvat", "Red Bull", 26);
team[8] = new Driver ("Felipe Massa", "Williams", 19);
team[9] = new Driver ("Valtteri Bottas", "Williams", 77);

for (var i = 0; i < team.length; i++) {
  if (team[i].number % 2 === 0) {
    console.log(team[i].name + " has an even driver number, it's " + team[i].number + ". " + team[i].firstName + " drives for " + team[i].car + ".");
  } else {
    console.log(team[i].name + " has an odd driver number, it's " + team[i].number + ". " + team[i].firstName + " drives for " + team[i].car + ".");
  }
};
```

Comment: That's exactly what I wanted and way simpler than anything I was trying to figure out, thanks Marcos! 

Can I ask, what is the [0] in the name.split(" ")[0] does it mean, split this at the first white space? So If [0] was [1] it would split it at the second white space (if there was one)?

Comment: Yes, `split()` method transform a string in pieces and store in an array, so if you split by spaces you'll obtain an array with all pieces separated. Then can access as an array with the position: `string[0]` first element, `string[1]` second element, etc. See more: https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/String/split

Comment: If this fits with your requirements, please, upvote and accept as correct answer. Thank you!

Comment: Thanks for the link and reply, already upvoted :) will accept now too, tried to a moment ago but it said I had to wait.

Comment: Yes, is not instantly to accept correct answer, you need to wait some minutes, but it's ok now . Thank you!